# RecyclerView is always null

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-support-library, android-recyclerview

I am trying to implement a `RecyclerView` in my app, but I can't make it work at all. It throws NPE and I can't find out why, because I've done everything according to official Google tutorials.

Logcat output:

```
04-26 23:04:41.823  22356-22356/com.example.app W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41670d88)
04-26 23:04:41.823  22356-22356/com.example.app E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.app, PID: 22356
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.app/com.example.app.PastEventActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #6: Error inflating class fragment
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2237)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2286)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1246)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:212)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5135)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:877)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:693)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #6: Error inflating class fragment
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:713)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.setContentView(ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.java:240)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.setContentView(ActionBarActivity.java:102)
            at com.example.app.PastEventActivity.onCreate(PastEventActivity.java:22)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2201)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2286)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1246)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:212)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5135)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:877)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:693)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.example.app.fragments.PastEventFragment.onCreateView(PastEventFragment.java:34)
            at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1700)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:870)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1044)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1146)
            at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4786)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:689)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.setContentView(ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.java:240)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.setContentView(ActionBarActivity.java:102)
            at com.example.app.PastEventActivity.onCreate(PastEventActivity.java:22)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2201)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2286)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1246)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:212)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5135)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:877)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:693)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**PastEventFragment.java**

```
public class PastEventFragment extends Fragment {
    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;

    public PastEventFragment() {

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
        View pastEvent = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_past_event, container, false);
        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) pastEvent.findViewById(R.id.pe_rv);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
        return pastEvent;
    }
}
```

**fragment_past_event.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/backrepeat">
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:name="@+id/pe_rv"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

**PastEventActivity.java**

```
public class PastEventActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    ActionBar actionBar;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_past_event);
    }
}
```

**activity_past_event.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <fragment
        android:name="com.example.app.fragments.PastEventFragment"
        android:id="@+id/fragment_pe"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

What's wrong with this code? I've tried many solutions from other questions, but none of them worked for me. I am asking for help, because I compared my code with official guides and some unofficial tutorials and it should work just fine.

Comment: delete the line `super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);` from `onCreateView` of `PastEventFragment`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `android:name="@+id/pe_rv"` in your layout.

You should use `android:id="@+id/pe_rv"`

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/pe_rv"
        />
```

Answer (score 0):

Please define the XML namespace, put `xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"` to `fragment_past_event.xml` LinearLayout below the main namespace

Answer (score 0):

after observing your logcat i think You have first exception on Inflating **RecyclerView** and then **NullPointer** exception.

Did you check your `android-support-v7-recyclerview.jar` library present in libs folder? if it is then check if your manifest file that has target sdk version to 21

```
 <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11" //or anything you need
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />
```

because after trying everything on internet i solved recyclerview inflating error by changing target from 17 to 21.

may be this can help for someone in future and not wasting days behind it as i did.

Answer (score -1):

You are missing the setContentView instruction in the PastEventFragment.java I had the same problem.